# GTM within Parent Domain and iframe

Tags: javascript, iframe, google-tag-manager

Within our site, we currently have the GTM tag implemented on the parent domain as well as within the iframe to capture cross domain tracking and Ecommerce data.

My question is, by having two GTM tags on the site, will that affect the metrics that are being recorded in Google Analytics? Will the visits be double counting as well as the Ecommerce data? If it is, is there a way to resolve this issue by utilizing the activity logic?

Thank you.

Comment: Just to clarify, you have GTM on the parent site as well as in the iframe, correct? Assuming the iframe is on a different domain, you won't be doubling your metrics because the iframed site is different.

Comment: Hey nyuen. Thank you for the prompt response. So a user going through the customer journey wouldn't be counted as having visited the site twice? One count through the parent domain GTM, and another through the iframe GTM but still technically under the parent domain like a shopping cart page for example.

Comment: Not if you have cross domain tracking in place. The session will be continued through both sites.

Comment: Great thank you so much!

Comment: Have you enabled cross-domain tracking in GTM? If so, it would work correctly. If not, I would verify using chrome debug tool as it might end up sending double data in case same GA id is being used.
Also I assume it is same domain, no sub-domain.

Comment: Hey @Sandeep. we have enabled cross domain tracking and are currently QAing. Quick question though. Would it be prudent instead of implementing two GTM tags (1 in domain and 1 in iframe) to just implement a GA tag in the iframe? Could cross domain tracking still work with this method keeping in mind the nature of iframes?

Comment: @HoyounLee Cross domain tracking in iframes is little tricky. I am not sure of your use case but I would keep one GTM tag only. Also look at these articles having great tips
https://www.simoahava.com/analytics/iframe-cross-domain-tracking-in-google-tag-manager/
https://www.knewledge.com/en/blog/2013/11/cross-domain-tracking-for-iframes-with-gtm/
Hope it helps.